# Error with php simple_html_dom parser

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

PHP experts.

I found a error while using the simple_html_dom Class.

My html strings have to be parsed are like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Y-shaped ZnO Nanobelts Driven from Twinned</title>

<meta name="site" content="Reports"/>

<meta name="description" content="Description with twinned planes {11&#"/>

<meta name="image" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"/>


...


</body>
</html>
```

I tried to get the meta tag named image with find("meta[name=image]"), however I couldn't.

I checked the reason and found that it is because of the characters '&#' in the middle of the above line of it.

```
<meta name="description" content="Description with twinned planes {11&#"/>
```

I got the content attribute of that meta tag like that

```
 Description with twinned planes {11&#"/>   <meta name="image" ....
```

So in this case, what should I do for letting the simple_html_dom parse the html correctly?

Otherwise is there any other library to parse this html correctly?

Comment: isn't it an issue that the {11&# should be {11&amp;#

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:  Use php [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

You can get meta using `getElementsByTagName` and get attribute value using `getAttribute`

```
$hml = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Y-shaped ZnO Nanobelts Driven from Twinned</title>

<meta name="site" content="Reports"/>

<meta name="description" content="Description with twinned planes {11&#"/>

<meta name="image" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom->loadHTML($hml);

$metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach($metas as $meta){

if($meta->getAttribute('name')=="image"){echo $meta->getAttribute('content');}

}
```

Output:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a
```

> Note:If you are loading content from a page use
>   `$dom->loadHTMLFile("your_pagename.html");` instead of this 
>   `$dom->loadHTML($hml);`